# since when does the google calendar api become a sensitive scope?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Been using google calendar api for a year now without the need to verify the app. Just this week it just appears to be needed verification because it is using sensitive scopes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Google policy question and not a programming question. We cannot speak on behalf of Google. Contact them directly via the email address they provided you.